# Make a reactive component with vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I need a Vue component to show some HTML content in `v-data-table` from Vuetify. I have seen this post [Vue 2 contentEditable with v-model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53899676/vue-2-contenteditable-with-v-model), and I created a similar code shown below.

My problem is the component is not reactive. When I click the "Test button", no content is updated in `HtmlTextArea`.

```html
<template>
    <div>
      <v-btn @click="doTest()">Test Button</v-btn>
      <HtmlTextArea
        v-model="content"
        style="max-height:50px;overflow-y: scroll;"
      ></HtmlTextArea>
    </div>
<template>

export default {
  name: "ModelosAtestados",
  components: { HtmlTextArea },
  data: () => ({
    content: "",
  }),
  methods: {
    doTest() {
      this.content = "kjsadlkjkasfdkjdsjkl";
    },
  },
};


//component
<template>
  <div ref="editable" contenteditable="false" v-on="listeners"></div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "HtmlTextArea",
  props: {
    value: {
      type: String,
      default: "",
    },
  },
  computed: {
    listeners() {
      return { ...this.$listeners, input: this.onInput };
    },
  },
  mounted() {
    this.$refs.editable.innerHTML = this.value;
  },
  methods: {
    onInput(e) {
      this.$emit("input", e.target.innerHTML);
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

This occurs because `HtmlTextArea` sets the `div` contents to its `value` prop only in the `mounted` lifecycle hook, which is not reactive.

The fix is to setup a [watcher](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers) on `value`, so that the `div` contents are updated to match whenever a change occurs:

```js
// HtmlTextArea.vue
export default {
  watch: {
    value: {
      handler(value) {
        this.$refs.editable.innerHTML = value;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/watching-value-change-in-vue-vskdw?file=/src/components/HtmlTextArea.vue:408-517)

Answer (score 0):

In the `@click` event binder, you have to pass a function. **You passed the result of an executed function**.

To make it work: `@click="doTest"` or `@click="() => doTest()"`.

How to debug such problems:

- Display the value you want to update on your template to check if its updated: `{{content}}`
- Use the [vue devtool extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vuejs-devtools/nhdogjmejiglipccpnnnanhbledajbpd?hl=en) to check the current state of your components

Comment: `@click="doTest()"` is a valid event binding, so that's not the problem.